# Virtual Interface Dtor && Dynamic_Cast

Tags: c++, rtti

I'm trying to downcast from an interface to a derived class but my virtual dtor kills it?

```
class IFOO
{
public:
 virtual ~IFOO(){};

 virtual size_t index() PURE;
};

class FOO : public IFOO
{
public:
 FOO() : size(5){};
 ~FOO(){};

 virtual size_t index(){ return index; };

 size_t index;

};


int main() {

 IFOO* A = &FOO();

 FOO* B = dynamic_cast< FOO* >( A );

 return 0;
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior, and the behavior you are getting.

Comment: I have RTTI enabled so I expect that a run time check is performed and a cast made to the derived class.  I keep getting a NULL pointer unless I remove the virtual dtor from my interface.

Comment: `PURE`: Is this a macro for `=0`?  Why not just type `=0`?

Comment: Also, please post *real* code.  This won't compile.

Comment: I'm sorry it is used in COM, I'm working with COM and I am sort of without peers and/or mentors so I really don't know any better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the address of a temporary in the line

```
IFOO* A = &FOO();
```

It should be

```
IFOO* A = new FOO();
```

I guess the code works if you remove the dtor from your interface, because in that case it will not be called, and you enter the realm of undefined behavior, in which anything is possible, even bad code working as expected.

Also, i would recommend that you do not write your class names in all capitals, because that is usually the convention for macros (unless your class names are macros, but surely, that cannot be). Also, don't use a macro (`PURE`) to make functions pure virtuals, this confusing 95% of the people that might have to read your code.

Comment: @PrettyFlower:  Because your compiler is cheating.  If you're using MSVC, turn off MicroSoft C++ Extensions, crank the warning level up to 4, and watch the schrapnel fly when you recompile.